# Printing HTML and SVG together

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, printing

I am trying to do something that 'should' be fairly simple. My program (Java, using SWT) has a button that when clicked, opens up a dialog with a browser component. This component hits one of our web-services using some specialized input, and the html that comes back contains a inline SVG image and some basic html (a table essentially). Some sample of what this looks like is as follows (truncated for ease of reading)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style> 
table {    border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;} 
table, td, th {    border: 1px solid black;} 
svg { top:0; left:0; width:612px; height:450px; display:block; margin:auto;}
</style>
</head>
<body><h1><b>Sample Heading</b></h1>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" 
      viewBox="0 0 244.8 180" enable-background="new 0 0 244.8 180" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

<!-- A whole lot of SVG commands here. -->

</svg>
<table border="1"><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th></tr>
<tr bgcolor="EDFEED"><td align="center">1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE: The CSS line for SVG is there because I was playing with how to auto-adjust the visual display size in the webpage. During the course of my debugging/testing, this has been added/modified/removed multiple times in various forms.**

**NOTE2: The SVG viewbox size comes from the initial SVG files I'm using. These come from outside of my process.**

This works perfectly fine for display in my dialog but where I'm having trouble is I want to allow my user to print the browser contents using a print button at the bottom of the dialog (So what they should get is the Image at the top, ideally scaled to fill a page width while preserve aspect ratio, with the table of supplementary information below it.) If I make a Javascript call from SWT of `window.print();`, it will print, but two peculiarities tend to occur.

The first is that if I leave that CSS line with the alterations to the SVG, it sometimes ends up writing off the page. I'm fairly sure this has to do with me doing something idiotic with SVG CSS styles that I can't seem to figure out.

The second is that it frequently ends up overwriting the top of the table element. This seems to happen even if I remove the CSS SVG line that is adjusting the image scale/size.

In addition, if I right-click in IE, and choose print-preview, it looks fine at least with the 'not overwriting the top of the table', but when it actually prints, the paper that is produced does not match what preview shows me. This behavior is consistent if I try this from outside my program in a normal IE window.

The HTML is generated dynamically upon the request to the webservice., but if similar HTML is fed into FireFox or Chrome, neither bug occurs (at least in my barebones testing.) Our app will always run on Windows PCs, and SWT uses IE (I'm using version 11 right now) under the hood, which is why I believe I'm running into this problem. I'm not a Web Developer or CSS guru, and I know enough to get myself into trouble, but I'm not sure how to fix this issue at the moment.

Any guidance or others who have dealt with HTML/SVG printing with IE would be appreciated. Thank you.